# Save rich text boxes as pdf files and send an email with attachments

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf-generation, richtextbox

I want to save rich text boxes as pdf files. Each time I save a file Adobe Reader can't open it.

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   SaveFileDialog MyFiles = new SaveFileDialog();
   MyFiles.Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf";
   MyFiles.Title = "Save As...";
   MyFiles.DefaultExt = "*.pdf";

   if (MyFiles.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
   {
      richTextBox1.SaveFile(MyFiles.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
      richTextBox3.SaveFile(MyFiles.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
      richTextBox4.SaveFile(MyFiles.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
      richTextBox5.SaveFile(MyFiles.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
   }
}
```

---

I also made send button to send an email with attachments but the problem is I'm unable to send the email:

```
        MailMessage MyMail = new MailMessage(richTextBox1.Text, richTextBox4.Text);
        MyMail.To.Add(new MailAddress(richTextBox4.Text));
        MailAddress mail = new MailAddress(richTextBox1.Text);
        MyMail.From = mail;
        MyMail.Subject = richTextBox5.Text;
        MyMail.Body = richTextBox3.Text;
        MyMail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(richTextBox2.Text));
        SmtpClient MySmtp = new SmtpClient(TheServer.Text);
        MySmtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        MySmtp.EnableSsl = true;
        MySmtp.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ThePort.Text);
        MySmtp.Send(MyMail);
```

Comment: You are saving text in rtf format, but setting extension to pdf. Just renaming file does not changes its format...

Comment: May be you can share more details, not able to understand your exact issue.

Comment: i think you should consider using an external library like http://itextpdf.com/ for the PDF creation

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, using the method, you cannot save the content of a RichTextBox in the PDF format.

Here you can find the currently available stream format types the can be used: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextboxstreamtype.aspx.

As you see, the main supported type is RTF (Rich Text Format), a plain-text multi-platform format: this is very different from PDF. Look [here](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) and [here](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format).

**EDIT:** I just answer to the questioneer's comment asking for some helping code:

```
// This method opens a dialog and save the content of the passed RichTextBox
private bool ShowRichTextBoxSaveDialog(RichTextBox richTextBox)
{
    SaveFileDialog newFileDialog = new SaveFileDialog();
    newFileDialog.Filter = "PDF Files|*.pdf";
    newFileDialog.Title = "Save As...";
    newFileDialog.Filter = "*.pdf";

    // If the user confirm the dialog window...
    if (newFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            richTextBox.SaveFile(newFileDialog.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            // Success!
            return true;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            // Error during saving!
            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("Error during saving: ", e.Message));

            return false;
        }
    }
    else
            // Aborted by the user!
            return false;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // NEXT WILL SHOW UP 4 DIALOGS, FOR ASKING THE USER 4 FILES TO SAVE!
   this.ShowRichTextBoxSaveDialog(richTextBox1);
   this.ShowRichTextBoxSaveDialog(richTextBox3);
   this.ShowRichTextBoxSaveDialog(richTextBox4);

   // HERE I ALSO CHECK IF THE SAVING IS SUCCESSFUL..
   if (this.ShowRichTextBoxSaveDialog(richTextBox5))
       MessageBox.Show("Success in saving :)");
   else
       MessageBox.Show("Failure in saving :(");
}
```

Comment: thanks alot but there's a little bit problem 'cause it saves only one richtextbox how can i make it save all of 'em ?

Comment: I think it's because you're using the same filename ("MyFiles.FileName"), and every call to richTextBoxX.SaveFile(...) will overwrite that file! So you have to ask the user for more files to save (= many MyFiles.ShowDialog()), or rename each file: File1.rtf, File2.rtf, ... If you want more details, ask!! :)

Comment: And also remember that if you call MyFiles.ShowDialog(), you will get as result ONLY one filename (the one chosen by the user)!

Comment: thanks again maxe but could u please show me how should rearrange my code? I appreciate your help

Comment: @user1629419 Yes...but please be patient and just wait 'till tomorrow, I'm away from PC now! :)

Comment: @user1629419 Take a look to my answer: I edited it for help you... If you need more help...just call! :)

Answer (score 0):

May be [Save PDF and MS Word File in C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/c8b468/save-pdf-and-ms-word-file-in-C-Sharp/) can help you!!!! It uses [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/)

Answer (score 0):

Using [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdflibrary/) or [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pdfsharp/) library can help you. As @JleruOHeP stated in a comment simply renaming the file won't work.

Answer (score 0):

As everyone has said, you can't simply save RTF and change the extension to make a PDF, they are incompatible formats. Among the many commercial components available, AbcPdf allows you to read in RTF, and then save the output as a PDF: http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-11.htm#note